# Mongo Aggregation to PostgresSQL

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, aggregation-framework, node-postgres

I am trying to convert Mongo aggregation to PostgresSQL equivalent and pass it to node pgp for execution -

Mongo aggregation:

```
[{"$group":{"count":{"$sum":1},"_id":{"media":"$media","user":"$user"}}},{"$sort":{"count":-1}}]
```

PostgresSQL format:

```
const qs = `SELECT ${columns.join()} FROM $1:name ${wherePattern} ${sortPattern} ${limitPattern} ${skipPattern} ${groupPattern}`;
```

Resulting pSQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "count", "media" AS "media", "user" AS "user", * FROM "Conversions"  ORDER BY   "count" DESC   GROUP BY ' "media", "user" '
```

Error from node postgres:

`error: Uncaught internal server error.syntax error at or near "GROUP"`

What would be wrong in the above formed query?

Comment: `order by` needs to go after `group by`

Comment: If I do that, I get this error: column "Conversion.objectId" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause+or+be+used+in+an+aggregate+function  (in a nutshell: remove the `*` from the `select` list)